# APIGateway Default Integration not working

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-cdk

I'm using the [AWS CDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/aws-apigateway-readme.html) to create my API Gateway REST API

I want to set up my `RestApi` to by default return a HTTP 404 so I set up

```js
this.gateway = new apigw.RestApi(this, "Gateway", {
  defaultIntegration: new apigw.MockIntegration({
    passthroughBehavior: apigw.PassthroughBehavior.NEVER,
    requestTemplates: {
      "application/json": `{
        "statusCode": 404
      }`
    },
    integrationResponses: [{
      statusCode: "404",
      responseTemplates: {
        "application/json": JSON.stringify({ "message": "Not Found" })
      }
    }]
  }),
  defaultMethodOptions: {
    methodResponses: [
      {
        statusCode: "404"
      }
    ]
  }
});

// UPDATE:
this.gateway.root.resourceForPath("/foo")
this.gateway.root.resourceForPath("/foo/bar")

....
```

However if I curl a `GET` to `/foo` I don't get a HTTP 404 back, but a 403. What am I missing?

Reading the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-apigateway.IResource.html#resourcewbrforwbrpathpath) (and the source code) for `resourceForPath` the default integration and default method options are being set correctly.

UPDATE:

I added in `this.gateway.root.resourceForPath("/foo")` but not getting the 404 back.

Comment: Please add the relevant language tag :)

Comment: Also - do you mean "curl a GET to **/foo/bar**"?

Comment: No, I mean `/foo`. It should return 404 as there is no resource at `/foo`

Comment: Is there authentication set on `/foo`? 403 is HTTP Forbidden

Comment: There is no authentication on any of my endpoints (yet). HTTP 403 is API Gateway's default response code.

Comment: Why do you have `this.gateway.root.resourceForPath("/foo/bar")` and not `this.gateway.root.resourceForPath("/foo")`?

Comment: I'm aware yes :) but if you had Cognito etc. it would also throw a 403 so just double checking!

Comment: > Why do you have this.gateway.root.resourceForPath("/foo/bar")

Bar is the real resource. Foo is just a parent collection type. Therefore there really isn't anything at Foo. I could create it however.

Comment: Does /foo/bar return 404?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary No. I've updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to create an `ANY` method on the parent resource (`/foo`).

```js
const foo = this.gateway.root.resourceForPath("/foo");

foo.addMethod("ANY", this.gateway.root.defaultIntegration, this.gateway.root.defaultMethodOptions)
```

However to me, this defeats the purpose of having a default integration/method options on the `RestApi` if I have to setup the methods manually for every path segment.